# how to display image in imageview from gallery, in fragment?

Tags: android, gallery

I tried to get image from gallery and capture from camera and display image in my imageView using fragment but the onActivityResult() does not response. Below is my code for capturing image from camera or gallery.

```
final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""),
                        PICK_IMAGE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.out.println("OnActivityResult Call");
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            imagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
            myImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + imagePath, ivUpload,
                    options);
        } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
            imagePath = getImagePath();
            System.out.println("IMAGE PATH===" + imagePath);
            myImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + imagePath, ivUpload,
                    options);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}

private String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else
        return null;
}

private Uri setImageUri() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date(CAPTURE_IMAGE).getTime()
            + ".png");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    this.imagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return imgUri;
}

private String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}
```

please give me any solution for that fragment. i also try with in activity. it is work but in fragment does not upload image from gallery.

Comment: what problem you are facing in fragment to get image from gallery?

Comment: when i choose any image from gallery at that time does not call onActivityResult(). why?

Comment: Override `onActivityResult` in parent activity of fragment and call `super.onActivityResult` in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Image path, you can directly display  image from image path..

You can write like this...

```
 imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

**`BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`** method allows you to decode image from file path. so you can set decoded image directly to the `ImageView` by `setImageBitmap()` method.

**Edit :**

Here I am adding sample code for picking intent..
You can take reference and see whats the problem there..

**To Call Image Intent**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

**Activity Result**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


       if (data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            img_user.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            btn_set.setEnabled(true);
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Try Again!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

}
```

This may help you..

Comment: sorry friends, i also try your answer but onActivityResult() does not call. i don't know what problem.

Comment: @EleshBaraiya :: see [onActivityResult not being called in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment) may help in solving issue

Comment: @Prags thanks your response but my problem is not solve. can you answer for what reason behind onActivityResult() does not called in fragment?

Comment: imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)); is  also works in fragments..

Answer (score 4):

That fragment does the job

```
public class ClientFormFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String TAG = "Test";

private ScrollView mScrollView;
private LinearLayout mFormView;

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
Uri myPicture = null;
Button buttonLoadImage;


private static int sId = 0;

private static int id() {
    return sId++;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Log.d(TAG, "onAttach(): activity = " + activity);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(): savedInstanceState = " + savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView(): container = " + container
            + "savedInstanceState = " + savedInstanceState);

    if (mScrollView == null) {
        // normally inflate the view hierarchy
        mScrollView = (ScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.bmr__fragment_client_form,container, false);
        mFormView = (LinearLayout) mScrollView.findViewById(R.id.form);

        buttonLoadImage = (Button) mScrollView.findViewById(R.id.select);

        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });


    } else {

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mScrollView.getParent();
        parent.removeView(mScrollView);
    }
    return mScrollView;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE  && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mFormView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }


}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated(): savedInstanceState = "
            + savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyView()");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDetach()");
}



public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Void> id, Void result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLoadFinished(): id=" + id);
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Void> loader) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLoaderReset(): id=" + loader.getId());
}



}
```

With that XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20px">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10px"
                android:paddingTop="20px"
                android:text="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:paddingTop="20px" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20px">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="City"
                android:paddingTop="20px"
                android:paddingLeft="10px" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:paddingTop="20px" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20px">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Zip code"
                android:paddingTop="20px"
                android:paddingLeft="10px" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:paddingTop="20px"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20px">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address"
                android:paddingTop="20px"
                android:paddingLeft="10px" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:paddingTop="20px" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20px">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Notes"
                android:paddingTop="20px"
                android:paddingLeft="10px" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textLongMessage"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:paddingTop="20px" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20px">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Status"
                android:paddingTop="20px"
                android:paddingLeft="10px" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioAccepted"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Accepted"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioWaiting"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Waiting" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioRefused"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Refused" />

            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20px">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pictures"
                android:paddingTop="20px"
                android:paddingLeft="10px" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/select"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="20px"
                android:text="Select" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20px">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="20px"
            android:text="Create" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

u can set image from gallery

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
            buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            }


        }
```

Comment: sorry.. my question related to Fragment not in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Override onActivityResult in activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Comment: sorry friend, i am using Fragment not Activity.

Comment: yes...but in main activity where you use add fragment use this code

Comment: i don't getting idea. because i am using below code.  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction();
  NewNoteFragment fragment = new NewNoteFragment();
  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flMain, fragment);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();