# How take a picture with a Fragment (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

I'm trying to take a picture in gallery, so i know do this in Activity, i use a Intent to call the gallery, and onActivityResult for take the path, but when i use a Fragment, i cannot to use "onActivityResult", can someone give a example of it using a Fragment and CustomDialog?

Comment: *but when i use a Fragment, i cannot to use "onActivityResult"* ... why?

Comment: Hi, try to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759227/how-to-display-image-in-imageview-from-gallery-in-fragment

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityResult(int,int,android.content.Intent) Here you go.It's available in Fragment..

Comment: There is no correct answer here... The question don't need it (take a look at my comment and sunil's comment and you will get a correct answer)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your fragment write this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // ******** code for crop image
            i.putExtra("crop", "true");
            i.putExtra("aspectX", 100);
            i.putExtra("aspectY", 100);
            i.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            i.putExtra("outputY", 356);

            try {

                i.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), 0);
            }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

In you Main Activity of the fragment write this code onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        try {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");
            img_user.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Try with this, it should work. Don't forget to accept the answer if correct.

Comment: *In you Main Activity of the fragment* ???? fragment does not contain Activity ... also what if multiple Activities use this fragment?

Comment: Every Fragment is having its own Parent Activity. You have to write this method in the Activity from where you have initialized your fragment.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try it!